# How to join two tables where one column in one table refers to 3 columns in other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've two tables as User and User_activity and the structure of them are,

**User**

```
id 
name
email
etc..
```

**user_activity**

```
id,
initiator_id,
source_id,
target_id,
activity_code,
activity
```

Here i want to select all the activity list for a user (i can refer them to source_id) with all names of initiator, source, target..

How to get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply join three times, using aliases for each f the three times you reference User...

```
SELECT
  user_activity.*,
  Initiator.Name   AS InitiatorName,
  Source.Name      AS SourceName,
  Target.Name      AS TargetName
FROM
  user_activity
INNER JOIN
  user             AS Initiator
    ON Initiator.ID = user_activity.initiator_id
INNER JOIN
  user             AS Source
    ON Source.ID    = user_activity.source_id
INNER JOIN
  user             AS Target
    ON Target.ID    = user_activity.target_id
```

Comment: Please could the down-voter elaborate on why, so that I can address your concerns?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sourceUser.name, targetUser.name, initiatorUser.name FROM user_activity
INNER JOIN User as sourceUser on sourceUser.id = user_activity.source_id
INNER JOIN User as targetUser on targetUser.id = user_activity.target_id
INNER JOIN User as initiatorUser on initiatorUser.id = user_activity.initiator_id
WHERE source_id = MyUserIdQueryValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DT1.*, U.name
  FROM (
        SELECT source_id, activity_code, activity
          FROM user_activity
        UNION 
        SELECT target_id AS source_id, activity_code, activity
          FROM user_activity
        UNION 
        SELECT inititator_id AS source_id, activity_code, activity
          FROM user_activity
       ) DT1
       JOIN User U ON DT1.source_id = U.id;
```